# Spring Boot + Integration Test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, integration-testing

I'm trying to write an integration test for a spring boot project. Unfortunately, I'm confused with the implementation.

Below sample code snippet tried

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MainApplication.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class PropertyControllerIT {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Test
  public void sample_test() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform(post("/property")).andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful());
  }
}
```

**Question**

- Do I need to have a separate `MainClass` with
  `@SpringBootApplication` annotated to support the integration test?
- Do we create a mock database or override the database configuration. If yes, how do we override the configuration
- Should we maintain a separate directory for integration-test similar to `java` or `test` like `integration-test`

Comment: Please, be careful when you select tags for your questions. Doesn't look like there is really something about Spring Integration in your question: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/spring-integration/info

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need to create any other classes annotated with
  `SpringBootApplication`.
- It's a good practice to run integration tests using in memory database for example H2. You can create a new `application-test.properties` file in `resources` folder inside of `test` directory. In order to use override properties you can run test with `test` profile. In order to run tests with `test` profile `@ActiveProfiles` can be used.
- You can keep your integration tests in the same `test` directory like unit test but they can be located in a separate package

Comment: So should we use the same `MainApplication.java` class and override the property as required?

Comment: Yes, `MainApplication` should be used as you are testing it. By the way, you may consider using `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)` if you want to have all application's beans in test context.

Comment: Okey. thank for the support. Q? If we are using the `MainApplication.java` it will use the database configuration already mentioned in the class. How do we override this value?